# Modifying entire row of an array based on a condition using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

`xNew = np.array([[0.50,0.25],[-0.4,-0.2],[0.60,0.80],[1.20,1.90],[-0.10,0.60],[0.10,1.2]])`

and another array:

`x = np.array([[0.55,0.34],[0.45,0.26],[0.14,0.29],[0.85,0.89],[0.27,0.78],[0.45,0.05]])`

If an element in a row is smaller than 0 or larger than 1 in `xNew` , that row should be entirely replaced by corresponding row in `x`. The desired output is:

`xNew = np.array([[0.50,0.25],[0.45,0.26],[0.60,0.80],[0.85,0.89],[0.27,0.78],[0.45,0.05]])`

I am looking for an efficient way to accomplish this using numpy functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use advanced indexing:

```
idx = ((xNew<0)|(xNew>1)).any(-1)
xNew[idx]=x[idx]
```

output:

```
[[0.5  0.25]
 [0.45 0.26]
 [0.6  0.8 ]
 [0.85 0.89]
 [0.27 0.78]
 [0.45 0.05]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, y in enumerate(xNew):
    if(np.any(np.greater(y,[1,1])) or np.any(np.less(y,[0,0]))):
        xNew[index] = x[index]
```